# MVC REST API Exclude parameter from returned Dto

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have the following (simplified) API controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetById(int Id)
{
    var res = await _service.GetById(Id);

    return Ok(res);
}
```

and `_service.GetById(Id)` is returns `returnDto`.

and `returnDto` is as follows:

```
public class returnDto
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string value{get;set;}
    public string extra{get;set;}
}
```

The issue is I want to exclude `Id` from `returnDto` when it is returned by the controller eg `GetById`

I know I can do this:

```
[DataContract]
public class returnDto
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string value{get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string extra{get;set;}
}
```

but this will exclude Id from all instances of this class, whereas I only want it excluded from this method.

I also know I can make a new Dto, but this seems a bit redundant to me.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can return anonymous type:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetById(int Id)
{
    var res = await _service.GetById(Id);

    return Ok(new {value = res.value, extra = res.extra});
}
```